# Wordpress wp-login and wp-admin in redirectloop to themself

Tags: wordpress, redirect, redirect-loop

I have a Wordpress website, where I can't login anymore. When I go to the wp-login page I get too many redirects. When I track the redirects, I see it is 302 redirected to itself, the exact same url.

**This is what I have tried so far:**

- Removed all plug-ins
- Changed the theme by database
- Removed wp-admin and wp-includes and uploaded them from a fresh wp download
- Triple checked htaccess, this is just the usual wp htaccess

Any idea how I can get back in my Wordpress? And if not, how to export all my content (posts, pages, media, prettylink redirects, users...) Thx!

Comment: Can you access the front end?

Comment: @AwaisUmar Yes front-end has no problems at all. It's just the wp-admin that we are having troubles with.

Comment: Can you please share the link?

Comment: http://4ty.nl/redirect-issue.php here it is. That will send you to the website.

Comment: I am getting internal server error, rather than the redirect error.

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is the message I and my collegues get from the browsers, also on phones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152612/discussion-between-awais-umar-and-bart-roelofs).